# Nodejs jsonArray parsing

Tags: json, node.js

I have a json object i want to get data from it! 
here is my json object

```
 "[androidVersionName=2.3.3, androidVersionId=10, androidId=fa0bef4b5a48eacb, mobileModel=sdk, mobileManufacturer=unknown, mobileId=GRI34, mobileProduct=sdk, applicationName=com.example.socketclient, applicationVersionName=1.0, applicationVersionCode=1, applicationState=INACTIVE, screenWidth=480, screenHeight=480, screenDensity=240, screenDensityName=hdpi, atdPackages=com.atd.panberes(1)]"
```

and here is my code :

```
 var json = JSON.parse(data);
 var androidVersionName = data.rowsets['androidVersionName'].row;
 console.log(androidVersionName);
```

and i get this error : 
Cannot read property 'androidVersionName' of undefined
how can i parse data from this jsonObject?

Comment: Your JSON object isn't actually valid JSON, if it is supposed to be object and not string.

Comment: how can i parse this kind of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A valid JSON based on your object:

```
{
    "androidVersionName":"2.3.3",
    "androidVersionId":10,
    "androidId":"fa0bef4b5a48eacb",
    "mobileModel":"sdk",
    "mobileManufacturer":"unknown",
    "mobileId":"GRI34",
    "mobileProduct":"sdk",
    "applicationName":"com.example.socketclient",
    "applicationVersionName":1.0,
    "applicationVersionCode":1,
    "applicationState":"INACTIVE",
    "screenWidth":480,
    "screenHeight":480,
    "screenDensity":240, 
    "screenDensityName":"hdpi",
    "atdPackages":"com.atd.panberes(1)"
}
```

Comment: i have changed my object to exactly what you said! now how can i parse data from it?

Comment: JSON.parse(data); should do it. If you want to be sure that everything is ok, you can use one of those online parser: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: Note also that you can't access a JSON property with "rowset". In your example, it will be "json.androidVersionName".

Comment: look at my code and output. code :
     console.log(data);
     var json = JSON.parse(data); 
     console.log(json.toString());  
     var androidVersionName = data.androidVersionName;
     console.log(androidVersionName);

Comment: output:
{"androidVersionName":"2.3.3","androidVersionId":"10","androidId":"fa0bef4b5a48eacb","mobileModel":"sdk","mobileManufacturer":"unknown","mobileId":"GRI34","mobileProduct":"sdk","applicationName":"com.example.socketclient","applicationVersionName":"1.0","applicationVersionCode":"1","applicationState":"INACTIVE","screenWidth":"480","screenHeight":"480","screenDensity":"240","screenDensityName":"hdpi","atdPackages":"com.atd.panberes(1)"}
[object Object]
undefined

Comment: the object you have to use after the parsing is "json". Not "data". Therefore, the correct way to get AndroidVersionId is: var androidVersionName = json.androidVersionName;

Comment: what a bad mistake! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse it to object. But you can transform it to JS object.

```
var data = "[androidVersionName=2.3.3, androidVersionId=10, androidId=fa0bef4b5a48eacb, mobileModel=sdk, mobileManufacturer=unknown, mobileId=GRI34, mobileProduct=sdk, applicationName=com.example.socketclient, applicationVersionName=1.0, applicationVersionCode=1, applicationState=INACTIVE, screenWidth=480, screenHeight=480, screenDensity=240, screenDensityName=hdpi, atdPackages=com.atd.panberes(1)]";
var result = {};
data.replace(/(\w+)=(\w+)/g, function(_, left, right) { result[left] = right; })
console.log(result);
```